# Facebook login not working: getUser() always return 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a facebook login, but it doesn't work, I've stripped down the code to the essential or problematic parts as shown below: I found out that the getUser method always return 0 whether a user is logged in to facebook or not, I've studied similar questions on SO but couldn't find the solution. What could be wrong? Thanks.

```
<?php
    require 'facebook/facebook.php';
    $app_id = "123456";
    $app_secret = "xyz";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $app_id,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }


    // Do stuff here       


    else {

    echo "$user";

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. I did this...

```
/**** FB APP DEETS  ****/
DEFINE ('APPID', '123');
DEFINE ('APPSECRET', 'xyz');
DEFINE ('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'biglongtokenthinginhere');

$config = array(
        'appId' => APPID,
        'secret' => APPSECRET,
);


        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $facebook->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Get User ID
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Then carry on with if($user) etc

So I believe you are missing the access token

To extend your access token, I used this. I added it before the if($user) and ran it once then commented it out. It displays a new access token on screen which you place in the script and it wont expire. Normally they only last for 2 weeks or something like that

```
 /*
 * EXTEND TOKEN - NOW EXPIRES NEVER
 */ 

//$graphUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APPID .'&client_secret='.APPSECRET.'&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token='.ACCESS_TOKEN;
//                
//$accessToken = @file_get_contents($graphUrl);
//parse_str($accessToken); //get the access_token param in the string and would be named $access_token
//if(!$access_token) $access_token = $accessToken; //if cannot be extended then just return the access token with 2 hours expiry
//echo $access_token;
//             
//exit(__FILE__.__LINE__);
```

Comment: Thanks.Can I put any value for the access token or how do I obtain it?

Comment: Nah you need to use a specific one relating to the app. From memory (its been a wee while!), you need to go here  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ select your app from the dropdown and click "get access token". On the popup that follows, go to the third page and check manage page I think it is. It will then give you a nice long access token.

Comment: As I say, its been a while but I think that was how I went about it :-)

Comment: You are correct, I've done that and it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work at first but there is a redirect-loop, any experience on that?